# How to identify in which of the 3 (GC) generations a Python object is?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, garbage-collection, ctypes

Python's garbage collection is based on reference counting, but in order to identify reference cycles, a generational [garbage collection](http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection) is used.

We're trying various ways to adjust the thresholds dynamically based on several signals, one of which is the similarity of objects in the youngest collection (sampled at some intervals say) with the ones in the oldest.

I've played a bit with the gc module (aka garbage collector interface) but couldn't spot a why that would allow me to retrieve information about which generation an object is located in.

Any hints/documentation/resources are appreciated.

Thanks!

**Update:**
My first attempt has been to use the [ctypes module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) which allows functions to be called from DLLs and shared libraries (.so). However, when using [find_library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries) of the ctypes.util, only standard C libraries have been found (libgc, libc, etc) which do indeed allows access to functions such as printf, strlen, etc

To access the functions/data structures in the [gcmodule](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/gcmodule.c) I've rebuilt CPython with the --enable-shared flag and use the resulted shared library's functions (listed with [nm](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/nm.1.php)).

Another possibility can be by using pythonapi and pyobject of ctypes, but [few](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576540-make-dictproxy-object-via-ctypespythonapi-and-type/) [tutorials](http://svn.python.org/projects/ctypes/trunk/ctypeslib/ctypeslib/contrib/pythonhdr.py) [exist](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls) online on its usage.

Any hints on how pythonapi, pyobject can be used with gcmodule.c are welcomed!

**Update2**
In gcmodule.c, I've identified the following function - already available through the [gc interface](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/gc.html) that is very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish (for a given (container) object (or memory address) return the number of generation in which it's tracked:

```
static PyObject *
gc_get_objects(PyObject *self, PyObject *noargs)
{
    int i;
    PyObject* result;

    result = PyList_New(0);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_GENERATIONS; i++) {
        if (append_objects(result, GEN_HEAD(i))) {
            Py_DECREF(result);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

My wrapper for a function similar to the one above would take an integer as a paramter (thus replacing the i in the above loop) and still using append_objects

Comment: CPython has three generations, but I don't think it uses the tri-color algorithm (which refers to how you *mark* objects as reachable; this is orthogonal to generational stuff).

Comment: Thanks @delnan - you're right, I confused the two.